# SVG filters and interpolated values

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization, svg-filters

I am creating a visualization with d3.js, and the effect I would like to achieve relies on a filter using feFlood and feBlend. For each path in the visualization, I need to interpolate a different `flood-opacity` value for the `feFlood` filter primitive. The filter is pretty simple:

```
<filter id="multiplyOverlay" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feFlood flood-color="steelblue" flood-opacity=".1" />
    <feBlend mode="multiply" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
```

I don't believe there is any way to pass a value in to the filter. Will I need to create a new filter for each path (about 200) in the visualization with the appropriate `flood-opacity` value? Or is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use different flood-opacities then you'll need to do multiple filters (although using 200 different opacity settings seems like overkill). (If it's any help to you, flood-opacity is a property and can be styled via CSS.)

Addition: Also remember that you can animate things with the SMIL <animate> element - if that's why you're doing the interpolation